# Calculating the sum of the table row from one table then join it with another table

Tags: mysql

Sorry,I'm not sure if I'm asking the right questions but this is what I want to happen. I have a table called tbemp:

```
EmpNumber | Name | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |
E-001     | Emp1 |   10   |   15   |    27  |
E-001     | Emp1 |   23   |   17   |    12  |
E-001     | Emp1 |   34   |   76   |    87  |
E-007     | Emp2 |   1    |   54   |    87  |
E-007     | Emp2 |   3    |   12   |    45  |
E-007     | Emp2 |   90   |   45   |    98  |
```

then output it like this:

```
EmpNumber | Name | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |
E-001     | Emp1 |   67   |   108  |    126 |
E-007     | Emp2 |   94   |   111  |    230 |
```

Comment: This is a basic aggregation query.  Do some research on `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
select EmpNumber, Name, sum(Value1) SValue1, sum(Value2) SValue2, sum(Value3) SValue3
from tbemp
group by EmpNumber, Name
```